# Seq2seq encoder returns same hidden state for all sentences in pytorch

Tags: lstm, pytorch

I'm trying to implement a seq2seq encoder-decoder that from an English sentence reconstructs the same English sentence. The decoder works fine (trained with teacher forcing it reconstructs valid sentences), but the encoder returns the same hidden encoding for any sentence.

I'm using pytorch and I liked to know if is this a common problem. What is the probable cause of this?

```python
hidden_size = 300
output_size = vocabularySize

class EncoderLSTM(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,emb_dim=vocabularySize):
    super(EncoderLSTM,self).__init__()
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(emb_dim,hidden_size)

def forward(self,X,h):
    X=X.view(1,1,-1)
    #print(X.shape,h[0].shape,h[1].shape)
    st,h2=self.lstm(X,h)
    #print(st.shape)
    return h2

def initHidden(self):
    result = (Variable(torch.zeros(1, 1,hidden_size)),Variable(torch.zeros(1, 1, hidden_size)))
    return result

...

hidden = encoder.initHidden()
for i in range(target_length):
    encoder_input=target_variable[0][target_length-1-i]
    hidden = encoder.forward(encoder_input,hidden)



...

for i in range(1,target_length):  


    pred,hidden = decoder.forward(decoder_input,hidden)

    target = target_variable[0][i].unsqueeze(0)
    values,ids = target.data.topk(1)
    target_id = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.array([ids[0][0]])).long())

    loss+= criterion(pred[0],target_id)

...

loss/=target_length
encoder_optimizer.zero_grad()
decoder_optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
encoder_optimizer.step()
decoder_optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You must not be looking at the entire hidden state for each new input sentence. They must be different if they are driving different output. Perhaps you're looking at some sort of final hidden state for the entire batch.